# Should I reformat a disk if Disk Utility asks me to?

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, disk-format, fat32

I have a FAT32 external disc that was suddenly unmounted as I was using it. When I reconnected it and tried to Repair it in Disk Utility, I got the following messages:

```
Verify and Repair volume “COMMON”
Checking file system** /dev/disk3s1
Can't open (Resource busy)
Volume repair complete.
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.
```

I then tried to do only a Verify, which succeeded:

```
Verifying volume “COMMON”
Checking file system** /dev/disk3s1
** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT
** Phase 2 - Checking Directories
** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters
29576 files, 36220416 KiB free (1131888 clusters)
```

I then re-tried the Repair, which succeeded:

```
Verify and Repair volume “COMMON”
Checking file system** /dev/disk3s1
** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT
** Phase 2 - Checking Directories
** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters
29597 files, 36219680 KiB free (1131865 clusters)
Volume repair complete.
Updating boot support partitions for the volume as required.
```

Does the fact that the Verify and the latter Repair succeeded mean that the filesystem is in a 100% good state? Or is the verification not exhaustive, which means that it's safer to reformat the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the error that showed up the first time was just `Can't open (Resource busy)`, I wouldn't worry about it. It didn't actually do anything the first time. I'm guessing you had a file open or something and it couldn't unmount the volume to repair. I think the reformat message shows up if a repair fails, for any reason, even if it has nothing to do with the filesystem.